# Problema envolvendo classes, vetores e tuplas

Tags: python, array, classes

Olá, estou um pouco confuso em relação ao conceito de listas e tuplas no Python. Em minhas pesquisas notei que tupla é um "tipo de lista imutável", mas, apesar da definição, ainda não consigo diferenciar propriamente no momento de desenvolver meu programa. Estou travado na seguinte questão:

- Construa uma classe denominada Turma que representará uma turma de alunos. Essa
  classe terá como atributos um array de strings contendo os nomes dos alunos e um array
  de floats contendo as notas de cada aluno.A classe deverá possuir um construtor que
  receberá os dois arrays como parâmetros, para que eles possam ser inicializados. A
  classe também deverá ter um método denominado calcularMediaNota que deverá
  calcular e retornar a média das notas dos alunos e um método imprimirAlunos, que
  imprimirá na tela a relação dos nomes dos alunos com as suas respectivas notas.

Para essa parte, eu pensei na seguinte resolução:

```
class Turma:
    nome = []
    notas = []
    def __init__(self,nome,notas):
        self.nome = nome
        self.notas = notas
    def calcularMediaNota(self):
        media = sum(notas)/len(nome)
        return media
    def imprimirAlunos(self):
        relacao = zip(nome,notas)
        relacaoSet = set(relacao)
        for i in range(0,len(nome)):
            print(relacaoSet)
```

A questão segue solicitando:

- Faça uma classe denominada TurmaDemo que deverá possuir um método main.
  Dentro do método main, deverá ser instanciado um novo objeto da classe Turma. O construtor da classe Turma deverá receber um array de strings contendo 10
  nomes de alunos e um array de floats contendo 10 notas, uma para cada aluno. Depois
  de instanciar o objeto, execute os métodos calcularMediaNota e imprimirAlunos a
  partir do objeto instanciado.

Nessa segunda parte eu tentei criar uma resolução utilizando atributos de teste, no entanto, acredito que o modelo que desenvolvi até então apresenta erros que me impedem de chegar na resolução final.

```
class TurmaDemo:
    def main(self):
        turma_dados = (
            ('Teste_1',10)
            ('Teste_2',9)
            ('Teste_3',8)
            ('Teste_4',7)
            ('Teste_5',6)
            ('Teste_6',5)
            ('Teste_7',4)
            ('Teste_8',3)
            ('Teste_9',2)
            ('Teste_10',1)
        )
        turma = [Turma(*i) for i in turma_dados]
        print('A média da turma é: {}'.format(Turma.calcularMediaNota(turma)))
        Turma.imprimirAlunos()
```

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

*Meu nível na linguagem Python e em POO ainda não é bem desenvolvido*

Se puderem me ajudar a encontrar um norte que eu possa seguir ou indicar os erros que venho cometendo, seria de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

## Sintaxe

Você claramente não executou o seu próprio código. Se tivesse executado, teria visto que esqueceu de usar o `self` ao acessar atributos da classe. O código gera um erro ao chamar os métodos `calcularMediaNota` ou `imprimirAlunos`.

## Validações

- Não faz sentido aceitar listas vazias, senão será feita uma divisão por zero ao calcular a média.
- Não faz sentido aceitar listas de tamanhos diferentes, senão a média será calculada errada.

Sugestão de código para atacar os problemas citados:

```
class Turma:
    def __init__(self, nomes, notas):
        if len(notas) == 0:
            raise Exception('notas não pode estar vazio')

        if len(notas) != len(nomes):
            raise Exception('notas e nomes devem ter o mesmo tamanho')

        self.nomes = nomes
        self.notas = notas

    def calcularMediaNota(self):
        media = sum(self.notas) / len(self.notas)

        return media
```

## Lógica - parte 1

O método `imprimirAlunos` imprime diversas vezes a relação de alunos e suas notas. Isso não faz sentido. O método deve imprimir uma única vez cada aluno e sua respectiva nota.

Sugestão de implementação:

```
def imprimirAlunos(self):
    for aluno, nota in zip(self.nomes, self.notas):
        print(aluno, 'tirou', nota)
```

## Lógica - parte 2

Na classe `TurmaDemo` você parece que tentou inventar moda e usou coisas que ainda não domina direito. Bastava ter feito um código mais simples, seguindo exatamente o que foi solicitado pelo exercício. Por exemplo:

```
class TurmaDemo:
    def main(self):
        nomes = [
            'Aluno A', 'Aluno B', 'Aluno C', 'Aluno D', 'Aluno E',
            'Aluno F', 'Aluno G', 'Aluno H', 'Aluno I', 'Aluno J'
        ]

        notas = [
            8, 9, 7, 9, 4,
            6, 8, 4, 5, 10
        ]

        turma = Turma(nomes, notas)

        print('Média', turma.calcularMediaNota())

        turma.imprimirAlunos()
```

Answer (score 0):

acredito que o primeiro problema que vc esta tendo é em como usar a primeira classe criada, `Turma`
ela recebe dois arrays, mas vc esta passando dos valores unitarios, acredito que ela deve ser instaciada desta forma

```
alunos = ('Andre', 'Bernardo', 'Carlos', 'Denilson', 'Edgar')
notas = (9, 8, 7, 9, 8)
turma = Turma(alunos,notas)
```

e tambem ja se pode adiantar e verificar se os metodos estão funcionando como se deve

```
turma.calcularMediaNota()
turma.imprimirAlunos()
```

sugiro que primeiro verificar se a classe Turma esta funcionando de acordo